# How to translate excel MINIFS function to dplyr code

Tags: r, dplyr

Two columns and the formulas are replicated below:

```
MinSell=IF(F2="SELL",0,MINIFS(C:C,B:B,B2,F:F,"SELL")-C2)

MaxSell=IF(F2="SELL",0,MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,B2,F:F,"SELL")-C2)
```

Column F includes transactionstatus

Column C includes Tradedate

account B includes AccountNo

I have a df containing hundreds of columns and millions of rows. Below is a small snippet of the df containing details of just one account

```r
AccountNo<-c(11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344)
transactionstatus<-c("BUY","BUY","SELL","SELL")
Tradedate<-c("2020-01-17","2020-01-16","2020-01-13","2020-01-12")

df<-as.data.frame(cbind(AccountNo,transactionstatus,Tradedate))
```

Expected OutPUT

```
MinSell = c(-5, -4, 0, 0)
MaxSell = c(-4, -3, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You cannot simply assume that anyone will know what language or software `MinSell=IF(F2="SELL",0,MINIFS(C:C,B:B,B2,F:F,"SELL")-C2)` comes from.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable containing the mindate and maxdate, then mutate columns with your condition.

### Setup

```r
library(dplyr)

# Tradedate must have Date class
df <- tibble(
    AccountNo = c(11223344,11223344,11223344,11223344),
    transactionstatus = c("BUY", "BUY", "SELL", "SELL"),
    Tradedate = as.Date(c("2020-01-17", "2020-01-16", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-12")))

df
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  AccountNo transactionstatus Tradedate 
      <dbl> <chr>             <date>    
1  11223344 BUY               2020-01-17
2  11223344 BUY               2020-01-16
3  11223344 SELL              2020-01-13
4  11223344 SELL              2020-01-12
```

### Solution

```r
# final df
binded <- tibble()

for (account in unique(df$AccountNo)) {

df_fltrd <- filter(df, AccountNo == account)

mindate <- min(df_fltrd$Tradedate[df_fltrd$transactionstatus == "SELL"])
maxdate <- max(df_fltrd$Tradedate[df_fltrd$transactionstatus == "SELL"])

solution <- df_fltrd %>%
  mutate(minsell = if_else(transactionstatus == "SELL", 0, as.numeric(mindate-Tradedate)),
         maxsell = if_else(transactionstatus == "SELL", 0, as.numeric(maxdate-Tradedate)))

binded <- bind_rows(binded, solution)

}

binded
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  AccountNo transactionstatus Tradedate  minsell maxsell
      <dbl> <chr>             <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1  11223344 BUY               2020-01-17      -5      -4
2  11223344 BUY               2020-01-16      -4      -3
3  11223344 SELL              2020-01-13       0       0
4  11223344 SELL              2020-01-12       0       0
```

Comment: So it looks like the min and max date is just taking the minimum and maximum of the entire trade date instead of just per account no. As each account number will have its own max and min trade date

Comment: You should have specified that in your question. you just need to add a for loop for every unique account. I edited the answer to include that.

Comment: Works! Thank you!